# VB.net checking date (year) to see if its an weird year

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, ldap

I'm looping through LDAP data placing some data from that into an MS SQL database. Out of the 7k+ LDAP records, a few have been causing an issue when trying to place the **lastlogin** into the database that has a DateTime format.

The problem is the date it has, **12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM**, is not correct and causes an error of

**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.**

I've been checking the date format before it inserts it into the database.

```
 If Not IsDate(empInfo.lastLogon) Then
    empInfo.lastLogon = Format(Now.AddYears(-1), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss")
 End If
```

But doesn't seem to catch the year of **1600** which seems to be causing that error above.

Is there any code I can use to detect those weird years and replace it with a random, legit date so it will place it into the database?

Comment: speculation: What is a valid date in the code is not a valid date in the database, probably because the database has an earliest date of 1753 something, whereas the code allows much earlier dates (such as the 1600 you cited). Try adding a clause to your IF statement `... or empInfo.lastLogon.year < 2000` (assuming your system wasn't in use last century).

Comment: @Turophile That seems to be correct but (1) Place that into its own answer so that I can give you proper credit and (2) How would I go about fixing the year when it does that *elseif*

Comment: If `empInfo.lastLogon` is a DateTime, then the use of Format is not necessary.  You can just use `empInfo.lastLogin = Now.AddYears(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is caused because what is a valid date in the code is not a valid date in the database, probably because the database can store an earliest date of 1753 something, whereas the code allows much earlier dates (such as the 1600 you cited).

Try adding a test for the year to your IF statement:

```
If Not IsDate(empInfo.lastLogon) OrElse empInfo.lastLogon.year < 2000 Then
    empInfo.lastLogon = Format(Now.AddYears(-1), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss")
End If
```

Instead of using a default of 1 year ago, you might want to use a marker value like `01/01/2000 00:00:00`. This will let you easily identify ones which didn't have a "real" value. But I don't know your business rules, so YMMV.

Comment: It seems from the code provided that `empInfo.lastLogon` is a String, so you can't use `empInfo.lastLogon.Year` . You will need to Parse the String to get a DateTime (or use String manipulation) in order to get the year.

Comment: @Blackwood empInfo.lastLogon is defined as a DateTime.

Comment: @StealthRT if `empInfo.lastLogon` is declared as `Date` in the code (is there a `DateTime` datatype in vb.net?) then it will always return **true** from `IsDate(empInfo.lastLogon)`, making the first condition in the IF redundant. I think this is what @Blackwood was getting at - you would use `IsDate` on a `String`, it isn't needed on a `Date`.

Comment: @StealthRT - Do you have `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or in your project's properties?  If so, then that code should not compile.  IIRC, Format returns string and you are assigning it to a DateTime variable.  In fact, Format is not necessary.  You can just use `empInfo.lastLogin = Now.AddYears(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

For months use `MM`, but for minutes use `mm`.

I.e.; you should use `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` instead of `MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss`.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: While this is correct, and I believe the OP should make this change, it doesn't answer the question that is being asked (how to avoid dates in the year 1600).

Comment: You are correct, @Blackwood. But I did change that part of the code - though it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
 If Not IsDate(empInfo.lastLogon) OrElse DateTime.Parse(empInfo.lastLogon).Year < 2000 Then
    empInfo.lastLogon = Format(Now.AddYears(-1), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
 End If
```

Comment: You need OrElse instead of AndAlso. We want to execute the code if [date is invalid] **OR** [date is earlier than Year 2000]